# No hay caso con las fechas en un query

Tags: php, mysql

Estoy peleándome con mysql y don PHP porque hacen cosas que no comprendo. Tengo una tabla que tiene estos campos:

```
    id         bigint(20)
    tit_eve    varchar(200)
    fec_dde    date
    fec_hta    date  
    organiz    varchar(200)
```

hago este query...

```
SELECT 
id, 
DATE_FORMAT(fec_dde, '%d-%m-%Y') AS fec_dde, 
DATE_FORMAT(fec_hta, '%d-%m-%Y') AS fec_hta, 
tit_eve, 
organiz 
FROM eventos 
WHERE (fec_hta >= '10-07-2017') AND eve_apr = 1 ORDER BY fec_hta
```

devuelve CUALQUIER COSA !!!
En PHP armo lo siguiente:

```
date_default_timezone_set("America/Buenos_Aires");
$diaActual = date("d-m-Y");
echo $diaActual;

$sql = "SELECT id, DATE_FORMAT(fec_dde, '%d-%m-%Y') AS fec_dde, DATE_FORMAT(fec_hta, '%d-%m-%Y') AS fec_hta, tit_eve, organiz FROM eventos WHERE (fec_hta >= '$diaActual') AND eve_apr = 1 ORDER BY fec_hta DESC";

echo $sql;

$resultado = $mysqli->query($sql);
```

Si bien la fecha que comparo es la de hoy: 10-07-2017 este query me trae fechas del 03-07-2017 y no ordena nada... 
No se que hacer !!!

PD: PHP ignora hasta la ordenación por ID !!! ni de forma ascendente, ni de forma descendente...

Comment: mas alla de php, el query anda en mysql?? es muy probable que no ande por los formatos de las fechas... no se si esta haciendo la comparacion como fechas...

Comment: En MySQL estaría funcionando y el order by también lo respeta

Comment: podrias mostrar el echo de diaActual y de sql?.. tambien siempre es mejor construir el query pasando parametros y no armarlo en linea, para evitar ataques..

Comment: y cuidado que tu php ordena desc en el query.. no es exactamente igual...

Comment: Hoy el $diaActual devuelve "11-07-2017" y si le puse el "desc" en el query para ver si reaccionaba pero no me da pelota... probe ordenar por id !!! y no hace absolutamente nada en php... en mysql funciona bien...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La parte del **WHERE** en tu consulta esta mal

```
... WHERE (fec_hta >= '10-07-2017') AND eve_apr = 1 ORDER BY fec_hta
```

Aun que utilices date_format en los campos, en la comparación del where no es tenida en cuenta.

Debería de quedar así para que tenga el resultado esperado, fecha como aaaa-mm-dd

```
... WHERE (fec_hta >= '2017-07-10') AND eve_apr = 1 ORDER BY fec_hta
```

Igualmente si sigues queriendo pasar la fecha como dd-mm-aaaa deberías hacer una conversión en el WHERE de string a date con **STR_TO_DATE**, aún que esto solo relentizara la consulta:

```
... WHERE ( fec_hta >= STR_TO_DATE('10-07-2017', '%d-%m-%Y') ) AND eve_apr = 1 ORDER BY fec_hta
```

Comment: Gracias @Xerif es verdad... si bien en el where ahora reacciona, tenía que pasarle la fecha como la maneja mysql en el formato YYYY-mm-dd para que la tuviera en cuenta... A pesar de que yo en el query la fecha la transformo al formato dd-mm-YYYY... aún así el ORDER BY LO IGNORA OLIMPICAMENTE !!!...

Comment: Marca la respuesta como aceptada, si fue la respuesta que soluciono tu problema.  La verdad que es más fácil pasarle a mysql como quiere la fecha y formatear la salida, parte de más eficiente.

Comment: claro... pero que opinas sobre el ORDER BY ? por qué no funcionará ? no ordena ni por id !!!

Comment: Es raro, probaste ha ordenar de forma ascendente (ASC) y descendente (ESC) y nada?

Comment: probe todo... fijate que yo ordeno por fec_hta, probe ASC y DESC y nada... despues se me ocurrió ordenar por otro campo, ID por ejemplo y NADA !!!

Comment: Puede abrir una pregunta nueva, poniendo los ejemplo de las consultas con las que le falla el ORDER BY, para no embarronar esto de comentarios. O continuamos en el chat.